# Create bar graph using Java

Tags: java, histogram, bar-chart

I am working on an assignment to create a bar graph using Java using random numbers, but I do not know how to code it properly, it keeps on giving errors when I move on to the next step.

```
public class BinSort {
    final int N_BINS = 0;                   //number of bins
    final int N_SAMPLES = 0;                //total random integers
    final float BIN_WIDTH = 0;              //width of the bin 
    int [] nums;                            //generate and store random numbers
    int [] binCount;                        //array
    int max = 0;                            //largest random number = (max-1)


    public void main(String[] args) {
        int nBins, nSamples;                    //initializers
        BIN_WIDTH = (float) (max/N_BINS);       //calculate BIN_WIDTH
        nums = new int[] {};                    //initialize nums array

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {         
            int array = nums[i];       
        }                                       
    }

    public void generateBins() {
        int bin;
        int [] binCount = new int [N_BINS];     //set binCount array with N_BINS elements
        for (int i = 0; i < N_SAMPLES; i++) {
            int array = binCount[i];
            bin = (int) Math.floor(nums[i]/BIN_WIDTH);
        }   
    }                                           

    public void printBins() {
        float freq;

        for(int i = 0; i < binCount.length; i++) {
            freq = (binCount[i]/N_SAMPLES);
            System.out.print(N_SAMPLES + " random integers in " + binCount + " sorted into " + N_BINS + " bins:");
            float binMin  = i * BIN_WIDTH;
            float binMax  = binMin + BIN_WIDTH;
            System.out.println(binCount[i] + freq + binMin + binMax);
        }
    }                                           
}
```

This code is incomplete, but I do not know what to do next. So, I am stuck. 
Can someone please help me?

Edit: The program does not compile after running in eclipse. It says the execution is terminated in the console.

Comment: Please break down your problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: 1) *"it keeps on giving errors"* What errors? Copy/paste them as an [edit] to the question. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Only static variables can be used in the static method . Below code is compiling fine:

```
public class BinSort {
    static final int N_BINS = 0;                   //number of bins
    static final int N_SAMPLES = 0;                //total random integers
    static float BIN_WIDTH = 0;              //width of the bin
    static int [] nums;                            //generate and store random numbers
    int [] binCount;                        //array
    static int max = 0;                            //largest random number = (max-1)


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nBins, nSamples;                    //initializers
        BIN_WIDTH = (float) (max/N_BINS);       //calculate BIN_WIDTH
        nums = new int[] {};                    //initialize nums array

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            int array = nums[i];
        }
    }

    public void generateBins() {
        int bin;
        int [] binCount = new int [N_BINS];     //set binCount array with N_BINS elements
        for (int i = 0; i < N_SAMPLES; i++) {
            int array = binCount[i];
            bin = (int) Math.floor(nums[i]/BIN_WIDTH);
        }
    }

    public void printBins() {
        float freq;

        for(int i = 0; i < binCount.length; i++) {
            freq = (binCount[i]/N_SAMPLES);
            System.out.print(N_SAMPLES + " random integers in " + binCount + " sorted into " + N_BINS + " bins:");
            float binMin  = i * BIN_WIDTH;
            float binMax  = binMin + BIN_WIDTH;
            System.out.println(binCount[i] + freq + binMin + binMax);
        }
    }
}
```